# Ejecutar un método después de unos segundos en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Buen día a todos. Les comento la situación, tengo un botón que al hacer clic se muestra el mensaje en un label y tengo un método que lo que debería hacer es mostrar otro mensaje después de 3 segundos, pero no me funciona. Lo probé en consola y el método si se ejecuta. No entiendo el motivo.

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" ID="btn" Text="Probar" />
</form>

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   lblMessage.Text = "hola";
   Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3)).ContinueWith(o => { lblMessage.Text = "3 segundos"; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tu llamas `Task.Delay(...` el codigo esta creando un nuevo thread para esa accion, pero btn_click termina y el render de la pagina continua. es parte del [ASP.NET Life Cycle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)).

En tu caso te conviene usar JavaScript para el delay.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btn').click(function () {
            var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

           setTimeout(function() {
             //Tu codigo aqui
             $('#lblMessage').text("Hola");
           }, delayInMilliseconds);

            
        });
    });
</script>
```